# Очистить историю коммитов git после клона с другого git`a

Tags: git

Склонировал с репозитория проект. Клонировал не последний коммит, а один из первых. Сделал свои изменения, запушил в свой git rep. В истории показывется 28 коммитов, с учетом коммитов другого автора. Показываются даже коммиты, которые были после того, который я скопировал. Как можно почистить историю, чтобы отображались только изменения сделаные мною?

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь получить? Свой единственный коммит без "прошлых" авторов? Или с одним прошлым? В истории гита нужно от чего-то идти в любом случае, даже когда вы делаете самый первый коммит в пустом репо, он идет после "нулевого".

Comment: @TotalPusher , да, мой единственный коммит, без "прошлых" авторов. Или это не представляется возможным?

Comment: Думаю, нельзя так сделать. либо все-таки один "прошлый" включить, либо делать другой репо с нуля, соответственно, других коммитов не будет. попробовал переименовать master в oldmaster, сделать коммит в master, и отправил master на гитхаб. Все равно прошлые показываются. А зачем вам это?

Comment: PS. Можно еще сделать rebase всех прошлых в "один свой коммит".

Comment: Вопрос решил удалением папки .git и новой инициализацией git. После этого запушил проект в git, в истории остался только мой один коммит. Проблема решена.

FYI, @TotalPusher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решил удалением папки .git и новой инициализацией git. После этого запушил проект в git, в истории остался только мой один коммит. Проблема решена.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы сделали только stage для файла и ещё не коммитнули его, всё делается через простой reset нужного файла (находящегося в stage):

```
git reset /assets/img/misty-and-pepper.jpg
```

Если же вы всё-таки коммитнули изменение, потребуется дополнительный предварительный шаг:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git reset /assets/img/misty-and-pepper.jpg
rm /assets/img/misty-and-pepper.jpg
git commit
```

Коммит будет откачен,а затем сделан новый коммит

Comment: ТС, похоже хочет что-то другое, чем откат коммита.